# Python: Programm Translation by using regexp

Tags: python, regex

I have a string code=`function add($n, m) {\t  return n + $m;\t}` and a list `args=["n", "m"]`. I need to fill missing `$` in front of arguments in code.

```
def programTranslation(code, args):
    argumentVariants = '|'.join(args)
    pattern = ???
    repl = ???
    return re.sub(pattern, repl, code)
```

The final code must be `function add($n, $m) {\t  return $n + $m;\t}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expressions with a replacement function. This is slightly more complex because:

- you need word boundary (otherwise `n` from `return` gets the "add $" treatment)
- you have to avoid adding a `$` if there's already one.
- you need to match the `$` if it's here, otherwise you cannot know if you have to add it (I prefer matching it, removing it if found, and prepend by `$` in all cases)

My proposal:

```
import re

code = "function add($n, m) {\t  return n + $m;\t}"

def program_translation(code,args):
    pattern = r"({})".format("|".join(r"([\$]|\b){}\b".format(a) for a in args))
    return re.sub(pattern,lambda m:"$"+m.group(1).lstrip("$"),code)

print(program_translation(code,['n','m']))
```

For clarity, the generated pattern is:

```
(([\$]|\b)n\b|([\$]|\b)m\b)
```

outputs:

```
function add($n, $m) {    return $n + $m;   }
```